# What does term `one viable function` refer to in [expr.static.cast]/4?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++17

[[expr.static.cast]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#4) (emphasis is mine):

> An expression e can be explicitly converted to a type T if there is an implicit conversion sequence ([over.best.ics]) from e to T, or if
>   overload resolution for a direct-initialization ([dcl.init]) of an
>   object or reference of type T from e would find at least **one viable
>   function** ([over.match.viable]). If T is a reference type, the effect
>   is the same as performing the declaration and initialization
>
> T t(e);
>
> for some invented temporary variable t ([dcl.init]) and then using the
>   temporary variable as the result of the conversion. Otherwise, the
>   result object is direct-initialized from e. [ Note: The conversion is
>   ill-formed when attempting to convert an expression of class type to
>   an inaccessible or ambiguous base class.  — end note ]

In the case of overload resolution of an object of type `T`, does the term **one viable funtion** refer to a constructor of the class `T` or to a conversion function in the class, of which `e` is an object.

Comment: Did you read [\[over.match.viable\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable)?

Comment: @NathanOliver Anyone else read overwatch instead?

Comment: @Borgleader I watched previews of the game

Comment: A constructor is only viable if `e` can be converted to the constructor's parameter. And that can happen either without a conversion function, or with a conversion function which then necessarily needs to be viable aswell, otherwise no user-defined conversion sequence can be formed. Or am I missing something? That's my gutfeeling about this, however I have not had a deeper look into the spec.

Answer (score 0):

[[dcl.init.general]/16](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16) tells you what overload resolution to do in order to perform the direct-initialization.

The operand to `static_cast` can't be a *braced-init-list* and I'll skip the special case where `T` is an array, because Clang and GCC never seem to allow it anyway.

So p16.6 will govern the case where `T` is a class. Other than the special case where the source expression is a prvalue of an exactly matching type (other than cv-qualification), where overload resolution is skipped, we see from p16.6.2 that overload resolution will be done among the constructors of `T`. Thus, if at least one viable constructor of `T` is found, it is considered that the `static_cast` can be performed (although it might be ill-formed, for example because overload resolution might fail to select the best viable function, or the best viable function might be inaccessible). If `e` has conversion functions that can convert to `T`, those conversion functions might participate in helping to make `T`'s copy constructor or move constructor viable.

If `T` isn't a class, but `e` is of class type, then p16.7 governs, and overload resolution is performed among the conversion functions of `e`. Thus, if at least one conversion function is viable, it is considered that the `static_cast` can be performed (again, it might be ill-formed still).

So the answer to your question of whether "one viable function" refers to a constructor or a conversion function is: it depends on which case of [dcl.init.general]/16 applies to the initialization.

I haven't covered the case of references yet. For that, see [dcl.init.ref].